# How do I use Mockito.doReturn in 2.7.x

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito

Mockito version: `v2.7.5/19`.

The exception:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.UnfinishedStubbingException: 
Unfinished stubbing detected here:
-> at com.mckesson.dex.dao.code.CodeDaoMockTest.testExcluded(CodeDaoMockTest.java:33)

E.g. thenReturn() may be missing.
Examples of correct stubbing:
    when(mock.isOk()).thenReturn(true);
    when(mock.isOk()).thenThrow(exception);
    doThrow(exception).when(mock).someVoidMethod();
Hints:
 1. missing thenReturn()
 2. you are trying to stub a final method, which is not supported
 3: you are stubbing the behaviour of another mock inside before 'thenReturn' instruction if completed
```

here's my code:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class CodeDaoMockTest
{
    @Mock( name = "entityManager") private HibernateEntityManager entityManager;
    @Spy @InjectMocks
    private CodeDao dao;

    @Test
    public void testExcluded() throws Exception
    {

        LabTestClassification ltc1 = new LabTestClassification();
        LabTestClassification ltc2 = new LabTestClassification();

        Mockito.doReturn( 533965, 533966)
            .when( dao.getNextCodeIntegerFromSequence( ltc1  ) );
```

it's worth noting that if I write this:

```
Mockito.when( dao.getNextCodeIntegerFromSequence( ltc1  ) ).thenReturn( 533965 );
```

I get a null pointer on a call to `entityManager`. My understanding is if I use `doReturn` then the actual `getNext...` will never be called, which is the goal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were close. Try with a bit different syntax:

```
Mockito.doReturn(533965).when(dao).getNextCodeIntegerFromSequence(ltc1);
```

Here is an article I wrote on [Mockito Stubbing](https://www.sourceartists.com/blog/unit-testing/mockito-stubbing/20) if you need a further read.